# how the fractional or intensity values with decimal points are categorized into bins in ImageJ histograms?

Tags: histogram, imagej

When I copied the list from the histogram produced using ImageJ, I got values like this.[The data was from 0 to 255 intensity levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsJLY.png). I don't understand how the intensity values like 42.75, 40.1, and 40.5 would be categorized. That is, will the pixel with intensity value of 40.5 be counted for intensity level 40 or 41?

I tried going through documentation but I couldn't find these details anywhere.

Comment: Your image appears being 32bit float and you create its histogram with 256 bins, then I guess the image must be imagined to be converted to 8bit which then gives the histogram values.